# Service firewall allows you to specify CIDR based rules for configuring source address that can access the service. What address would you specify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

Your Server IP Address is 172.20.30.75 and it is part of 172.20.30.0/24 subnet. You have a service that needs to be accessible only from the above server. Service firewall allows you to specify CIDR based rules for configuring source address that can access the service. What address would you specify?

- 172.20.30.75/24
- 17.20.30.0/24
- 17.20.30.75/32
- 17.20.30.0/32

Comment: The excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499) explains how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

`172.20.30.75` can be part of multiple subnets /32, /31, /30, ....

If you want only `172.20.30.75`, then the CIDR is `172.20.30.75/32`.